# NameError: global name is not defined

Tags: python, class, namespaces

I'm using Python 2.6.1 on Mac OS X.

I have two simple Python files (below), but when I run

```
python update_url.py
```

I get on the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update_urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    main()
  File "update_urls.py", line 4, in main
    db = SqliteDBzz()
NameError: global name 'SqliteDBzz' is not defined
```

I tried renaming the files and classes differently, which is why there's x and z on the ends. ;)

#### File sqlitedbx.py

```
class SqliteDBzz:
    connection = ''
    curser = ''

    def connect(self):
        print "foo"

    def find_or_create(self, table, column, value):
        print "baar"
```

#### File update_url.py

```
import sqlitedbx

def main():
    db = SqliteDBzz()
    db.connect

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to do:

```
import sqlitedbx

def main():
    db = sqlitedbx.SqliteDBzz()
    db.connect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @Wizzard: Because that's how modules, variables, and attributes work in Python.

Comment: Because `import sqlitedbx` imports `sqlitedbx.py` into its own namespace. If you don't want to prefix it with the filename, import it differently into your script's namespace: `from sqlitedbx import @Wizzard: SqliteDBzz`.

Comment: @Tamás thank you, your comment helped me understand why I had a similar problem!

Answer (score 5):

try

```
from sqlitedbx import SqliteDBzz
```

Comment: @Wizzard: Note this is the same as "import sqlitedbx" plus "SqliteDBzz = sqlitedbx.SqliteDBzz" (followed by "del sqlitedbx", if you want to get technical).

Answer (score 3):

Importing the namespace is somewhat cleaner. Imagine you have two different modules you import, both of them with the same method/class. Some bad stuff might happen. I'd dare say it is usually good practice to use:

```
import module
```

over

```
from module import function/class
```

Answer (score 0):

That's How Python works.
Try this :

```
from sqlitedbx import SqliteDBzz
```

Such that you can directly use the name without the enclosing module.Or just import the module and prepend 'sqlitedbx.' to your function,class etc