# Global from User defined GUI

Tags: variables, user-interface, global, maya

So I think my problem is my understanding of Global Variables and subroutines. Plus the Lists at the start
Heres my code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ff1b16aa4093a2929896

If I place it into maya highlight it and press the Play icon. It works and the GUI opens and I can run the whole process from the  GUI okay. But if I save it and try and import it as module it doesnt work properly and the reset button disppears and I get this:

# NameError: global name 'Reset' is not defined #

EDIT: I'd put Reset in the variable but for the procedure for some reason.

Comment: Can we see a code example? Are you using Maya's UI options or PyQt? Why use global variables instead of encapsulating your functions in a class?

Comment: I don't really understand classes. I will look into them

Comment: Is this all of your code? I'm trying to understand what it is you're doing with your code overall, but you've got functions that you have no call to. Are you trying to have the data stick after your UI is gone? If so why? Whats the requirement for that? I'd like to help, but I can't figure out what you're doing.

Comment: its like 400 lines of code in total,  how can I upload it here?

Comment: There are several places online you can post code. I like https://gist.github.com/ however to be fair I'll list alternatives: pastebin, pastie, chop, snipplr, codesnippets and about a hundred others. Pick one and then post the url so folks can help you out.

Comment: Thanks have uploaded :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977167/nameerror-global-name-is-not-defined?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [optionVar](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/Commands/optionVar.html) command.

In general, the entire user interface of Maya is open source. If you want to know how something works, you can simply find the script that implements it. Also try not to avoid learning MEL.

Comment: Will do, I just started learning python for a project at Uni.