# Getting 'NameError: name '<my function>' is not defined' error

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, namespaces, syntax-error

I have created a Python 2.7 module. Its name is memories and saved in memories.py. The code is:

```
import random

def get_a_random_memory(length, lower_sum_range, upper_sum_range):
    # Start with a blank memory
    memory = list()

    # For each bit along the length we add a random value
    for i in range(0, length):
        memory.append((2 * random.randint(0, 1) - 1))

    return memory
```

When I try to run I get the following error.

```
>>> import memories
>>> print get_a_random_memory(10, 1, 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'get_a_random_memory' is not defined
```

I checked with print os.getcwd(). memories.py is in my current working directory.

Here is a screenshot of my working environment.
[image]

Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried `print memories.get_a_random_memory(10, 1, 10)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NameError: global name is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977167/nameerror-global-name-is-not-defined)

Comment: @MorganThrapp, that one was with a built-in function but this one is about my custom function. Do you suggest that I remove that one?

Comment: It's exactly the same problem. It doesn't matter who wrote the module.

Comment: @MorganThrapp, adding memories. solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be accessed as follows

```
import memories
print memories.get_a_random_memory(10, 1, 10)
```

If you do want to import it into current namespace, you can do

```
from memories import get_a_random_memory
```