# dbConnect() - NameError: global name 'db' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, chromecast, alexa-skills-kit

I'm new to the forum, but I'm curious to know if any of you all have been working on an skill to integrate Alexa with chromecast?

I've been using this GitHub repository, but I've gotten stuck. I've posted this help/issue request in GitHub and I'm wondering if any of you all have run into a similar issues.

Also,

Here is a screen shot of one of the issues, if you're able, please refer to the GitHub issue I've posted. The information provided there is a lot more specific issue.

...I'm wondering if it's the configuration of dbConnect? Any ideas or may better solutions?

Thank you so much for reading this!

[image]

Comment: You forgot to include a link to the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977167/nameerror-global-name-is-not-defined.